My Undo History broke
I can't use undo or redo
Undo History only contains "Original


Hello and welcome. Do you have a question we can answer? This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. For bug reports please see Where to Report a Bug. If the issue is in or caused by a third party addon, please report it to the addon author instead.

I guess this has to do with the Global Undo setting in the Preferences: CTRL+Z in Object Mode takes me to last change in Edit Mode. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Is this upon opening the file, or have you done anything since opening?
